# how to go to gitlab management in browser?

Tags: gitlab

I installed free plan of gitlab in my server. according to [official documentation](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#ubuntu),

> 4. Browse to the hostname and login.
>      On your first visit, you'll be redirected to a password reset screen to provide the password for the initial administrator account. Enter your desired password and you'll be redirected back to the login screen.
>      The default account's username is root. Provide the password you created earlier and login. After login you can change the username if you wish.

how can i access to gitlab login page that installed in my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you configured it to listen on. Most likely, on top of `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` it will say "external_url '....'".
That would be the URL that you could try.

Comment: thanks, i want to edit some elements of gitlab user interface in browser. how can i find html, css and setting files of gitlab in my server?

Comment: The package installs itself in `/opt/gitlab`. What you are looking for is likely under `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app`